# JBuilder raw string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jbuilder

I have a string defined in a controller @string which is already json formatted.

Now in my view.json.jbuilder, I try to only add this json output to my view and it doesn't seem to work as the json is always encoded (add / before every " chars).

I tried

> json.some_node_name raw(@string)

And

> json.some_node_name @string

Without success, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
json.some_node_name JSON.parse(@string)
```

that way you parse the json, then re-make it into JSON. Not sure if jbuilder has a way of using pre-JSONified strings directly.

Comment: Yeah it does work! Thought I'd like to avoid having to parse it back to a hash since it's already a json string.